# ionic slide on click go to some slide

Tags: ionic4

I used ionic 4 slide.

```
 <ion-slides pager="false">
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide (click)="next(slides, 5)">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </ion-slide>
 <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 4</h1>
      </ion-slide>
 <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 5</h1>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

in the ts file i have used following code.

```
next(slide, index) {
this.slides.slideTo(index)
}
```

click event is working good. After click the slide is stopped. I found this fix from the following location.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/jump-to-an-specific-slide-with-ion-slides-component/48840/5

How can i fix this issue??

Comment: the slides are zero indexed so there technically isn't a slide '5' in your next method but it will still work :)

Answer (score 4):

Think your missing the template reference variable #slides

```
 <ion-slides pager="false" #slides >
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide (click)="next(slides , 4)">
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </ion-slide>
 <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 4</h1>
      </ion-slide>
 <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 5</h1>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

and .ts

```
next(slide, index) {
    slide.slideTo(index)
}
```

### 2nd way

cmd (in project) -

```
npm i @ionic/angular
```

.html-

```
  <ion-slides pager="false">
          <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 1</h1>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide (click)="next(4)">
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 3</h1>
          </ion-slide>
     <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 4</h1>
          </ion-slide>
     <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 5</h1>
          </ion-slide>
        </ion-slides>
```

.ts -

```
import {IonSlides} from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
      @ViewChild(IonSlides) slides: IonSlides;


next( index) {
    this.slides.slideTo(index)
}
}
```

Comment: Worked fine on my android phone, you 100% you changed both? is any errors in the console ?

Comment: tried the first option. after click the previous and next not working. swipe too. this issue only in device.

Comment: any errors in the console ? what device you using ?

Comment: redmi 8 device.